# Convert dBm/Hz to dBW/ 100 Hz?

Tags: digital-communications, power-spectral-density

I am trying to convert -13 dBm/ Hz into corresponding dBW/100 Hz? Can you please point me in the right direction.

Do I need to convert dBm to dbW by adding -30 first?

Comment: yes. What else would you do? And then, you convert to "per 100 Hz" by adding another +20.

Answer (score 3):

You can always convert from dBm to dBW by subtracting 30dB.  That's because dBm is a power relative to 1mW and dBW is the power relative to 1W -- and 1mW / 1W = 1/1000, which is -30dB.

Any time you get confused by dB, or dBm, or dB<insert weird unit here>, you can always do the calculation in the parent units.  I.e., -13dBm is 0.05mW, or 0.00005W -- and if you work that out, then it is, indeed a 30dB difference.

Answer (score 1):

Let's to the step by step. $dB/Hz$ is a unit for power spectral density so it's a function of a power/energy and bandwidth.

When converting from $dBm/Hz$ to $dBW/Hz$ you change the reference from $1mW$ to $1W$. That's a factor of 1000 or an offset of 30 dB. So we have

$$-13 dBm/Hz = -43 dBW/Hz$$

When converting from $dBW/Hz$ to $1dBW/100Hz$ you increase the bandwidth a factor of 100 or an offset of 20 dB. Hence we have

$$-13 dBm/Hz = -43 dBW/Hz = -23 dBW/100Hz$$